# Oracle SQL: NVL Function

Tags: sql, oracle

If Value does not exist in Table B, replace value with null-

**Table A Employees**

```
ID,NAME
1,Sam               
2,Jon
3,Nick
```

**Table B Sallery**

```
ID,Sallery
1,500
2,1000
```

**Desired results:**

```
NAME,Sallery
Sam,500
Jon,1000
Nick,
```

**What I got so far:**

```
 Select A.NAME, 
        NVL(Select Sum(B.Amount) from Sallery B where B.ID=A.ID  ,null)
 From Employees A
```

I want to avoid useing the "Case When exists" expression

Thank you

Comment: You tell us what you got so far, but forget to tell us your issues with it :-) As you see from Patrick Hofman's answer, it is a left outer join you are actually looking for. However, your approach would work too, only you'd need additional parentheses around your sub-query to make it syntactically correct: `NVL((Select Sum(B.Amount) from Sallery B where B.ID=A.ID) ,null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `left outer join` for this:

```
select a.name
,      sum(b.amount) amount
from   employees a 
left
outer
join   sallery b
on     b.id = a.id
```

The `sum` will return `null` if there are no rows in `b`.

Comment: Thanks, Works alot faster

Comment: @user3651825: Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked most when your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.name, A.sal 
FROM (SELECT SUM(NVL(salary, 0)) sal, id
     FROM salary
     GROUP BY id)A, Employees B
WHERE A.id=B.id
```

Comment: Just a remark: You should no longer suggest to use the old comma-separated join syntax which was replaced with explicit join syntax (INNER JOIN ... ON ...) more than twenty years ago.

Comment: Internally both are same.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is a matter of readability and of explicit joins being less prone to errors.